# jquery form plugin passing empty values

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a hidden div that is shown in a facebox modal window once the edit info button is clicked.

```
<div id="editlog" style="display:none">
        <h3>Enter a new weight and/or photo.</h3>
        <form id="editlogform" action="editweight.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" id="edittrigger" />
            <table width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6" border="0">
                <tr><td>New Weight.</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" maxlength="3" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>New Photo</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="file" name="photo" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="button" value="submit" id="editlogsubmit" class="button"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

As you can see it also passes a photo. Here is the jquery to submit the form.

```
$('#editlogsubmit').live('click', function() {
    $('#editlogform').ajaxSubmit({ 
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.t);
        }
    });
});
```

I on the server side I `print_r()` the variables and they are all empty? I can only pass something if I use jquery to grab the value using the id, not the name. I think it may have something to do with the fact that the div is in a modal but I am not sure. Any ideas on why the variables are empty?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Have you checked firebug to see if it shows the variables going through there? Also `.live` is deprecated, don't use it.